# Android Jellybean WebviewClient SSL Handshake Error

Tags: android, ssl

I am using WebviewClient in my app which opens a URL which uses TLSv1.2 protocol. I can open the URL on Kitkat and above and I researched it is because the webengine of Kitkat and above OS moved to Chromium.

Google decided to ditch the JellyBean Webkit. Could anyone help me how I can open the url in jellybean webviewclient with the handshake error.

The error I get is

```
W/chromium_net: external/chromium/net/http/http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc:865: 
0218/114458:WARNING:http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc(865) Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant  
02-18 11:44:58.320 16133-16249/com.mercia.android.dev E/chromium_net: external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:792:   
[0218/114458:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(792)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
```

Comment: Hey, did you find any workaround to make it work on JellyBean?

Comment: any solution to this